# is there a postgREST like module in python flask which can automatically provide REST interface to postgres?

Tags: python, postgrest

I know I can spin up another service in my cloud for postgrest, but wondering if there is a python module that I can use in my service that will provide the same.

Basically, I should be able restfully do GET/POST postgres db tables just by including a python module and initilizing the db connection.

Comment: do you use django? in one of the project that I've worked, we use TastyPie, and the DB is postgress... https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Please check this - https://github.com/jeffknupp/sandman2

Comment: Check out https://github.com/pyeve/eve-sqlalchemy